# What does it mean root directory of a usb stick?

Tags: upgrade, updates

I know that a root directory is the top directory , but a Chinese machine needed to be updated , the company told me to add the files of the update to usb under the path  : `/udisk/` .

How to add  the files  in Ubuntu  under `/udisk` and **/** is the usb root directory   .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `/` is root, and `/udisk` means put it in the folder `udisk`, which you will see when you open the USB.

Can you not simply copy them?

Comment: Like tim said but if you dont have a udisk folder just make one on the top level and put your files in it